# Configuring Squid on localhost as Reverse proxy error

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I want to install squid 3.1.19 in the reverse proxy mode on my localhost machine on the port 3128, I am using Nginx as the webserver on my localhost on the port 8080... I installed squid, and changed its config file.. but when running squid, i keep getting the error

```
FATAL: Bungled squid.conf line 65: http_port 3128 accel defaultsite=localhost no-vhost
Squid Cache (Version 3.1.19): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.020 seconds = 0.012 user + 0.008 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 12784 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
```

My squid.conf file looks like this.. I dont know the origin of this error.. Googling didnt help either.

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT


#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all



# Squid normally listens to port 3128

http_port 3128 accel defaultsite=localhost no-vhost
cache_peer localhost parent 8080 0 no-query originserver name=myAccel


acl our_sites dstdomain localhost
http_access allow our_sites
cache_peer_access myAccel allow our_sites
cache_peer_access myAccel deny all              




# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Answer (score 2):

The option no-vhost doesn't exists. If you don't want vhost, don't write that option in the line.